# What Local Databases are avaliable for Javascript?

Tags: javascript, xml, database, json, html

I'm developing a project in Server Side Javascript (SJS) using POW webserver. The result of the project will be a local application for users that will interact with a sort of "Database" of Answers and Questions (It's like a Quiz Builder).

Actually we are just starting and we are storing informations into JSON files (POW allows read/write of plain files), but I'm looking for a more efficient way to store and recall information from the DB (something SLQ-like).

Is there any possibility of doing this using Javascript? One of the requirements is that the user doesn't have to install a DB server (Mysql, Sqlite ecc) so it should be a Javascript-pure way, or even XML-HTML5 way (I'm not going to use WebDB or similars).

Comment: That software project (POW) appears to be inactive; does it even work with modern Firefox versions (like, the ones that Mozilla is actively supporting with security updates etc.)? The wiki appears to be completely empty. Maybe I found the wrong URL, but as it is I can't imagine basing a product on that.

Comment: @Pointly : Actually that's my opinion too and I'm trying to convince my professors to trow it away and go on with other solutions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

POW provides simple access to SQLite DB, saved in pow/data folder. 
http://davidkellogg.com/wiki/Pow_db

Answer (score 3):

There are two client-side database features in modern browsers: IndexedDB and Web SQL.

Neither is fully supported across the current versions of the various browsers, but IndexedDB seems to be the one which is going to win -- the Web SQL is apparently no longer being maintained, and may be dropped entirely.

You can find out more about them both, and their respective browser support on the [CanIUse website](http://caniuse.com/#search=database).

[EDIT] As mentioned by @Raynos, there is also LocalStorage, which actually appears to have much better cross-browser support than either of the other two mentioned above. Given the browser support (even IE8 supports it!), this would seem to be the best option for the time being, even though it isn't as fully featured as the other options above.

Here's the [CanIUse details](http://caniuse.com/#search=localstorage) for LocalStorage.

Hope that helps.

Comment: There is also localStorage which has some posibility.

Comment: there's also some obscure propietory permanent storage system in IE6 and IE7 called [userData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531424(v=VS.85).aspx). Really though use [store.js](https://github.com/marcuswestin/store.js)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but actually it's not what i'm looking for... anyway, great site CanIUse!! thnx for sharing :)

Comment: @Juan - no worries. But glad you found CanIUse useful -- it's definitely one of the best resources available right now for this kind of thing (quirksmode.org is also good, but is getting a bit dated now. still useful for checking features for old IE-compatibility, though).